# AngularJS isn't sorting date and time properly(ng-repeat)?

Tags: angularjs

{
order: 12093810923,
dateandtime: 2/14/2014 @ 14:15:22,
type: pt,

order: 456456464654,
dateandtime: 2/14/2014 @ 14:18:22,
type: pt,

order: 5464564654654,
dateandtime: 2/15/2014 @ 13:10:22,
type: pt,

}

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter:searchText | orderBy: 'DateandTime':false">
```

how do i sort the 'dateandtime' field in reverse order? when the above code renders, everything is in different positions. I am thinking it could be due to the way date is formatted, possibly due to the '@' character. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: If you can post the data as properly formatted JSON, it'll be easier to tell what's wrong

Comment: You can't perform an orderBy on an object, you need an array. And also as said above me, that JSON isn't well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments suggest, you need to return an array of objects in your JSON, so this kind of structure

[{....},{....},{....}]

So each of those orders would be contained in the objects, and therefore ng-repeat can iterate over correctly.

The date format like you say is not correct and if you are trying to use as us, it won't be treated as a proper date object in Javascript so sorting will not work. You will need the server to return a suitable format in a string ('d-M-Y H:m:i' format kind of thing) in your objects and then depending on your AngularJS code that's receiving the data, e.g a success\promise in a $http request, you could look through the results and create a new array of data with the cleaned up parsed date values in or just directly convert the date values correctly in the response before then assigning to $scope in the controller for the view where your ng-repeat is.